# What is required to pass URL as arguments in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a selenium python script for automation. Want to pass IP as an argument to create URLs to be used in the script.

```
node_ip = sys.argv[1]
app_url = str("https//"+node_ip+":5200/admin/")
```

```
def site_login():
    browser.get(app_url)
```

But when i run the script i get the following error :

```
# python3 test.py 192.168.20.10
```

```
  File "test.py", line 81, in <module>
    site_login()
  File "test.py", line 33, in site_login
    browser.get(app_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

Could you help fix this ?

Comment: At first glance `str("https//"+node_ip+":5200/admin/")` should be `str("https://"+node_ip+":5200/admin/")`.

Comment: You're probably better off with formatted strings than forcing the whole thing to be `str`. Something like `f'http://{node_ip}:5200/admin'` or `'http://{}:5200/admin'.format(node_ip)`

Comment: `print(app_url)` before you try to navigate using it... what does it print? You should spend some time learning how to do some basic debugging.

Comment: @jayg_code : Thanks. `f'http://{node_ip}:5200/admin'` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `f'http://{node_ip}:5200/admin'` or any string formatting methods in Python. Personally I haven't seen much examples where `str()` is used except when converting a non-string variable to string (i.e., `f'I counted {str(x)} times!'`).